# Number of ways to write a tuple of positive integers as a sum of tuples with certain constraints

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, balls-in-bins

There are $N$ boxes into which we put $mn$ balls in $m$ steps, where in each step we insert $n$ balls, each of which goes into a different box. In how many ways can we do this so that box $B_i$, $1 \leq i \leq N$, contains $b_i$ balls? Note we may assume that $\sum_{i=1}^N b_i = mn$, otherwise we can not do this.

This is equivalent to the following problem: In how many ways can we write $(b_1, \ldots, b_N)$ as a (component-wise) sum
$$
(b_1, \ldots, b_N) = (a_{1,1}, \ldots, a_{1,N}) + (a_{2,1}, \ldots, a_{2,N}) + \cdots + (a_{m,1}, \ldots, a_{m,N}),
$$
where the entries of each of the tuples $t_k$ = $(a_{k,1}, \ldots, a_{k,N})$, $1 \leq k \leq m$, belong to $\{0,1\}$ with precisely $n$ of its entries being $1$?

For example, take $N = 3$ and $m = n = 2$ with $(b_1, b_2, b_3) = (2,1,1)$.
Note that 
\begin{align*}
(2,1,1) &= (1,1,0) + (1,0,1)\\
&= (1,0,1) + (1,1,0),
\end{align*}
so that there are only $2$ ways to write $(2,1,1)$ in such a way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can $b_i=0$ for some $i$?

Comment: I guess one could allow this if it would be useful, but in any case, if one does, the problem boils down to considering the $b_i's$ which are not $0$..

Comment: I think the heart of the problem is to get a (hopefully nice enough) generating function of the set $\{(a_1, \ldots, a_N) \in \{0, 1\}^N \mid \sum_{i=1}^N a_i = n\}$, then raise it to the $m$-th power and retrieve coefficients.

Comment: Here's a reference that's looks useful: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/linalg.pdf